# Why React Scheduler uses MessageChannel instead of queueMicrotask?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scheduled-tasks

I noticed that in React Scheduler [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0965fbcab3616523086d05c1069492cc171cbb80/packages/scheduler/src/forks/Scheduler.js#L605), it uses `MessageChannel` instead of `queueMicrotask` for scheduling micro task:

```js
let schedulePerformWorkUntilDeadline;
if (typeof localSetImmediate === 'function') {
  // Node.js and old IE.
  // There's a few reasons for why we prefer setImmediate.
  //
  // Unlike MessageChannel, it doesn't prevent a Node.js process from exiting.
  // (Even though this is a DOM fork of the Scheduler, you could get here
  // with a mix of Node.js 15+, which has a MessageChannel, and jsdom.)
  // https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20756
  //
  // But also, it runs earlier which is the semantic we want.
  // If other browsers ever implement it, it's better to use it.
  // Although both of these would be inferior to native scheduling.
  schedulePerformWorkUntilDeadline = () => {
    localSetImmediate(performWorkUntilDeadline);
  };
} else if (typeof MessageChannel !== 'undefined') {
  // DOM and Worker environments.
  // We prefer MessageChannel because of the 4ms setTimeout clamping.
  const channel = new MessageChannel();
  const port = channel.port2;
  channel.port1.onmessage = performWorkUntilDeadline;
  schedulePerformWorkUntilDeadline = () => {
    port.postMessage(null);
  };
}
```

Why not just use `queueMicrotask`? Is there any advantages of MessageChannel over `queueMicrotask`?

Comment: Maybe it predates it? Why not ask the maintainers?